# Mysql SQL triming leading 0 in varchar field without triming last 0 before . (dot)

Tags: mysql, trim

I want to clean "numbers" in VARCHAR field.

```
Examples:
________________
a. 001    : 1
b. 01     : 1
c. 0      : 0
d. 00.1   : 0.1
e. 0.0    : 0
f. 0.001  : 0.001
```

I considered:

```
TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM t.field)
```

but this would work only on a and b record.
Others would become .1 or .0,...
Any ideas on how to handle this problem?

Edit:
Sorry I forgot to add essential info.
Some records may contain other characters.
i.e.: 0.1 km

Answer (score 1):

Try it by casting

```
SELECT CAST(fieldName AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 1):

Treat them as numbers?

```
UPDATE SET yourfield = CAST(yourfield AS signed)
```

mysql will re-convert to varchar when it does the actual update.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the idea. I can't treat them as numbers as some contain other characters i.e 0.1 km. I guess I could try to strip non digit characters when I would CAST them. I'll try. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I overlooked essential info. I have edited the question.